# Handle undefined as an object

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, declaration, new-operator

Is there a technique / framework, which creates and stores a new object into an undefined variable when it is handled as an object?

F.e. writing

```
some.thing = 7;
```

Gives an error describing, that undefined's ( some's ) property could not be set.

So now, we have to go back, and write

```
some = {};
some.thing = 7;
```

which looks **almost** unnecessary to me, since it is obvious, that I'd like to use some as an object.

---

It would be very comfortable this way:

```
hospitals.sectors.doctors = [];
hospitals.sectors.doctors[ 0 ].age = 32;
```

This looks way more efficient, and simple than

```
hospitals = {};
hospitals.sectors = {};
hospitals.sectors.doctors = [];
hospitals.sectors.doctors[ 0 ] = {};
hospitals.sectors.doctors[ 0 ].age = 32;
```

Comment: Why not `var some = { thing: 7 };`?

Comment: I'd like to avoid this structure, since in deeper ( multi-dimensional ) objects it's rather confusing.

Comment: Since `thing` is a property of the `some` variable then surely it makes sense to define the object variable THEN assign the property - this is how all other languages work to my knowledge. And as far as I know there isn't a way to automatically handle the exception when assigning properties to all undefined objects.

Comment: It is right, it makes perfect sense, but still, it'd be comfortable to declare objects this way in a complex oop web app.

I'll append an example to my answer of where it might be comfortable in practise.

Comment: Yes I think an example would help me see where you're coming from a little more. But coming from a background in object oriented languages it's second nature to define an object before assigning properties. In fact JS is very loosely typed, since it doesn't require the properties to be defined before being assigned values.

Comment: I know, it is usual, and pretty universal, but let's think outside the box.
Javascript is a heavily preprocessed language. I can't imagine, there's no way doing this, when ECMA6 standard is coming up with all those comfortable, and logical syntaxes.

Comment: To me, seeing `hospitals.sectors.doctors[0].age = 32` without ever seeing where `sectors` or `doctors` is defined would be very confusing. Declaring and defining are and should be separate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to assign `7` to `some.thing` and `some` should **not** be declared at all beforehand, use Cory's suggestion of `var some = { thing: 7 };`.

If you are trying to assign `7` to `some.thing` and `some` **might** be declared/defined already (or even if it is declared, may or may not be set to `undefined`), use

```
(some = (some || {})).thing = 7;
```

or (a more readable solution, though not a one liner)

```
some = (some || {});
some.thing = 7;
```

The one caveat with my solution is that you might get undesired scoping on `some` if it isn't declared ahead of time. An example of where it would be undefined but still declared (and thus the scope would be what is expected):

```
function assignThing(some) {
    (some = (some || {})).thing = 7; /* one liner solution */
    return some;
}

var foo = assignThing(); /* the parameter 'some' is undefined, but declared */

var bar = assignThing({}); /* the parameter 'some' is defined
                            * (though empty) and declared */

(baz = (baz || {})).thing = 7; /* Unless you have this declared
                                        * elsewhere this *should* be the
                                        * global scope */

var foobar; /* declared, not defined */
(foobar = (foobar  || {})).thing = 7; /* now defined */
```

Edit: Created a namespace solution like what anddoutoi suggested.
First example of usage (`hospitals`) uses the optional nature of the third parameter, which defaults to "undefined".

Second example (`hospitals2`) passes undefined.

Third example (`hospitals3`) passes another object (I happened to create it inline).

For the example you (the OP) provided, my `hospitals` example is the closest to an exact match. I don't know of a way to auto-magically create an object hierarchy besides using a canonical name string + a function.

```
function create(canonicalPropertyName, value, root) {
    root = (root || {});
    var names = canonicalPropertyName.split(".");
    var current = root;

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        /* Ensure the property exists */
        current[names[i]] = (current[names[i]] || (i < names.length - 1 ? {} : []));

        /* We're recursing down the object tree */
        current = current[names[i]];
    }

    return root;
}

var hospitals = create("sectors.doctors", []);
hospitals.sectors.doctors[ 0 ] = {};
hospitals.sectors.doctors[ 0 ].age = 32;
console.log(hospitals);

var hospitals2 = create("sectors.doctors", [], undefined);
hospitals2.sectors.doctors[ 0 ] = {};
hospitals2.sectors.doctors[ 0 ].age = 32;
console.log(hospitals2);

var hospitals3 = create("sectors.doctors", [], { name: "City Hospital" });
hospitals3.sectors.doctors[ 0 ] = {};
hospitals3.sectors.doctors[ 0 ].age = 32;
console.log(hospitals3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many frameworks have a `namespace()` method/function that helps you achieve what you want.

- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_namespace
- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-namespace

Example:

```
Ext.ns('hospitals.sectors.doctors') = [];
var doctors = Ext.ns('hospitals.sectors.doctors');
doctors[0] = {
    age : 32
};
```

I myself don't like this *pattern* as it adds unnecessary dependencies and work.

Answer (score 0):

you could write an own handler to do the job

```
function createObjectProperty(objNameString, objPropertyString, objValueString) {
window[objNameString] = {};
window[objNameString][objPropertyString] = objValueString;
return window[objNameString];}

var test = createObjectProperty("some", "thing", 7);
alert(test.thing);
```

the call would look like:

```
createObjectProperty("some", "thing", 7);
```

and it alerts "7".You also could check before creating the new object, if it exists. I would iterate over the object and gather all attributes, check for duplicate and append my new attribute + value if you need such functionality. Otherwise the new object will overwrite the old one. Hope this is what you are searching for

working fiddle (update):

https://jsfiddle.net/a922bopj/1/